# Android App does not appear on Emulator

Tags: android, gradle

i'm facing an issue right now.

My code seems fine, but i don't understand why my app does not appear on my emulator.

If someone could give me some advices or responses

it would be appreciated,

Thanks :)

My Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

My Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "blackbeardstudio.login_register"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Manifest, intent filters relating to certain activity must be inside the activity block for that activity. For this instance of using `MainActivity` as launcher activity (the one that will appear in the apps launcher menu on home screen):

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `intent-filter` into `activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your launcher intent filter needs to be inside the `activity` tag for your `MainActivity`.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```